# Unable to create parboiled parser

Tags: java, parboiled

I have created a parser class for the parboiled framework according to [this simple example](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki/Simple-Java-Example):

```
package my.package;

import org.parboiled.BaseParser;
import org.parboiled.annotations.BuildParseTree;

@BuildParseTree
public class QueryParser extends BaseParser<Object> {
    //some rules
}
```

If I try to create parser as shown in the example

```
QueryParser parser = Parboiled.createParser(QueryParser.class);
```

I get an exception at that line:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: my.package.QueryParser$$parboiled cannot be cast to org.parboiled.BaseParser
    at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:56)
    ...
```

I'm really not doing anything special that is not done in the example. The only difference is that the parser and and the class calling it are in different projects but I can't imagine why this should matter. The dependencies between the projects (which are Eclipse plugin projects) should be alright.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong or where the mistake could be?

Comment: The gethub source shows this line defining createParser() `public static <P extends BaseParser<V>, V> P createParser(Class<P> parserClass, Object... constructorArgs) {` which doesn't return a boolean. Could this be a version issue? Do you have the latest version of the Parboiled jars?

Comment: @LeeMeador everything is up to date. Parboiled 1.1.4 and the needed asm 4.0

Comment: Try changing `parser` to an `Object` and using a debugger to look at what the type actually is. Perhaps you can look at the code for that type and see whether it extends BaseParser but not QueryParser. That might give you a clue.

Comment: That was one of the first things I've tried but I'd actually would have to look that up in `Parboiled.java:56` which doesn't have a local variable for examination.

Comment: That's why you change it to `Object`. So you can store it and look at it. You breakpoint or single step to the next line in the code and just kill the process after examining the debugger info.

Comment: No I understood what you meant. Meanwhile I moved all the parboiled relevant code to one project and it works. I think I'll keep it this way and vote for a close. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: None of the reasons for closing are really applicable so I decided to answer my own question. Thank again!

Comment: Maybe the annotation processing effectively uses the project path to search for the annotated classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually seems to have something to do with the run configurations. I moved all the parboiled relevant code to one project and it works. I think I'll keep it this way because it is better encapsulation anyway.